# Network Configration on Virtual machine

Tags: linux, centos, virtualbox, putty, ifconfig

I am creating a Linux environment for learning purpose. I just installed ubuntu for base OS, and I installed centos(minimal) in Virtual box.

My goal is to access the centos from ubuntu by Putty.

But in Cent OS, I'm not able to configure `ip` and `hostname`.

While trying on centos `#ifconfig`  it is telling command not found.

Please help me to resolve this one. Thanks in advance

Comment: may be `ifconfig` command is not in your path. Try `/sbin/ifconfig`.

Comment: What CentOS version are you using ?

Comment: @Digisec CentOS 7

Comment: @iamauser on that location i can find ifcfg only

Comment: @ARUN, see my answer

Comment: Did you choose "minimal install" from the standard installer .ISO or did you use a different install image that is "minimal"? Some minimal install options for Linux distributions forgo many tools. You could edit the /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-en?* file by hand.

Answer (score 0):

As of CentOS 7 there is no more `ifconfig`. They replaced it with `iproute2`. The following [link](https://www.tty1.net/blog/2010/ifconfig-ip-comparison_en.html) has comparison examples.

For further information on how to set permanent configuration for your network please check this [link](http://lintut.com/how-to-configure-static-ip-address-on-centos-7/) for examples.

Furthermore, they replaced `sysvinit` with `systemd`.

Finally, I would like to finish with a question. Why the need to run a windows application, like putty, on top of Linux to `ssh` when you can simply `ssh` from a terminal ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a minimal CentOS-7, `ifconfig` is not available. It has been replaced with `ip` commands. Package `net-tools` that provides `ifconfig` can be installed separately using `yum` on CentOS-7.

```
yum install net-tools

# execute ifconfig
/sbin/ifconfig
```